How to compare 2 file and print the first match of the string until the blank line
I need to do a backup of all users that have been deleted so I have 1 file for the backup and another file for the list of users to backup. I want it use awk to retrieve the details and would like to do it inside awk without while condition.
1st file
dn: uid=testuser1,ou=people,ou=identities
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person

dn: uid=testuser1,ou=people,ou=identities
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person

2nd file
dn: uid=testuser1,ou=people,ou=identities

I have used below but it's too slow
while read line
do
delcommand=" awk '/"$line"/,/pattern|^$/' backup.ldif >> backupfiledeleted.txt
eval "$delcommand"
done < listtodelete.txt

Expected to print the set of details for the user:
dn: uid=testuser1,ou=people,ou=identities
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person

NOTE: We are working on a linux environment.

Combining Awk with a shell while read loop is an antipattern. Related: Counting lines or enumerating line numbers so I can loop over them - why is this an anti-pattern?

does the first file really consist of duplicated blocks of text? if not then please update the question to show a couple different blocks of lines ... one block that matches your search, one that does not match your search

With your shown samples and in GNU awk please try following code.
awk '
FNR==NR{
  arr1[$0]
  next
}
split($0,arr2,"\n") && arr2[1] in arr1 && !arr3[arr2[1]]++
' file2 RS= file1


Succinct and lucid code! Thank you!

You can make blank lines a record separator, denoted by an empty RS as pointed out by @RenaudPacalet in the comment, and a newline a field separator, so that you can easily output a blank-line-separated record without a while loop:
BEGIN {
    RS = ""
    FS = "\n"
}
NR == FNR {
    for (i = 1; i <= NF; ++i)
        a[$i] = 1
    next
}
a[$1]-- > 0

Usage:
awk -f program.awk backupfiledeleted.txt backup.ldif

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing1/IntentTurboDeclaration

I would harness GNU AWK for this task following way, let file1.txt content be
dn: uid=testuser1,ou=people,ou=identities
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person

dn: uid=testuser1,ou=people,ou=identities
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person

and file2.txt content be
dn: uid=testuser1,ou=people,ou=identities

then
awk 'FNR==NR{arr[$0];next}($0 in arr){p=1;delete arr[$0]}/^$/{p=0}p' file2.txt file1.txt

gives output
dn: uid=testuser1,ou=people,ou=identities
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: person

Explanation: when processing first file (which is file2.txt) i.e. where file number row (FNR) is equal to global number row (NR) I store whole line ($0) as key in array arr and go to next line, so no other action is undertaken. For other file if current line ($0) is one of keys arr I set p value to 1 and delete said key (preventing later matching for that particular line from triggering that action), for empty file (/^$/) I set p value to 0 after all that I filter lines using p value (i.e. printing only lines where p is non-zero).
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

Best I can tell, this is what you want, using any awk (untested since the sample input isn't adequate to test with):
awk '
    NR == FNR { dns[$0]; next }
    $1 == "dn:" { f=($0 in dns) }
    f
' listtodelete.txt backup.ldif

Alternatively:
awk '
    NR == FNR { dns[$0]; next }
    $1 in dns
' listtodelete.txt RS='' ORS='\n\n' FS='\n' backup.ldif

